# Prepending string to name of raster output using ArcPy?

Tags: python

Right now my script searches for rasters, reprojects the raster, and replaces the extension with `jpg`.

My output looks like a list of rasters named `fm-4-65.jpg.` , `fm-4-66.jpg`, etc.

How could I make it so that the code adds "test_" to the output raster file name so that the resulting name looks like `test_fm-4-65.jpg`?

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy, sys, os

InFolder = r"C:\test_in"
OutFolder = r"C:\test_out"
OutSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(26918) # NAD83 / UTM zone 18N

arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for Ras in rasterList :
     inRaster = os.path.join(InFolder, Ras)
     spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(inRaster).SpatialReference
     if spatial_ref.type <> "Unknown":
          outFileName = "{}.{}".format(os.path.splitext(Ras)[0], "jpg") # Remove .sid and add .tif to Ras filename
          outRaster = os.path.join(OutFolder, outFileName) # Path and Filename of output raster (.tif)
          arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (inRaster, outRaster, OutSR)
```

Comment: I think you should look at Python string formatting or concatenation. There will be many examples of this on [so].

Answer (score 4):

You can add "test_" to the start of your filename by adding it in your `outFileName` line:

```
outFileName = "{0}{1}.{2}".format("test_", os.path.splitext(Ras)[0], "jpg")
```

- `{0}` takes the value `test_`
- `{1}` takes your existing filename (without the extension) from `os.path.splitext(Ras)[0]`
- `{2}` adds `jpg` as the file extension

These are then combined using `format()` at the end of your string into a new filename that is then passed to your tool.